# View pager indicator doesn't appear - Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5462#!description) to create an indicator for a viewPager (in Android). I simply want to show to the user that he can change the view. For some strange reason, even when I create the view and set it up, it doesn't show. Here's the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.instructionViewPager);
    adapter = new InstructionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    };

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);

    ViewPagerIndicator viewPagerIndicator = (ViewPagerIndicator) 
    findViewById(R.id.view_pager_indicator);
    viewPagerIndicator.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPagerIndicator.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);
```

And I have it in the .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/biometricTextLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Biometric"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/instructionViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/biometricTextLabel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/instructionbContinue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/instructionbBack"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <com.github.vivchar.viewpagerindicator.ViewPagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:delimiterSize="8dp"
        app:itemSize="8dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/instructionbContinue"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/instructionbBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Go back"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've added all the xml of the layout.

EDIT 2: I add the pageAdapter, it's simple:

```
public class InstructionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> fragments;

public InstructionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your full xml code.

Comment: @SureshKumar ok there it is :)

Comment: Could you add the `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` ?

Comment: Could you post your `InstructionPagerAdapter` ? And I try to use your code to test.

Comment: @KeLiuyue there you have it, if you need anything else let me now and thanks!

Comment: It seems you have not added any fragment to your adapter yet. Add one and try again.

Comment: @SureshKumar Ok I was adding it after doing all that code. It seems I needed to do it before, and now it work. Post it as an answer and I will give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not added any fragment to your adapter yet. If you are adding the fragment to you adapter after assigning adapter to your viewpager, then try to notify your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

change the layout like below template , this works good for me ,

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```